# JBoss, thousand of threads in WAITING state, is this normal?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

I am running `JBoss 5.0.0` on `Solaris 10 SPARC` with java `build 1.6.0_27-b07`.

When I check with `ps -eLf | grep -c 'Xss256k'` (I use java command line arg `Xss256k` to minimize thread size) I am seeing 8000 threads (and counting)..

Thread dump also reveals a lof of process in WAITING state, is this normal?

Here is an excerpt of the thread dump (I have thousand of thread like this),

```
        Thread: pool-159-thread-10 : priority:5, demon:false, threadId:2231, threadState:WAITING

            - waiting on <0x169635f> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
            sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
            java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
            java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
            java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: The name of the thread (`pool-159-thread-10`) suggests that the JVM created 159 thread pools and that the current one contains at least 10 threads. And no - this isn't normal, typically applications/server aren't producing that many `ExecutorService`s...

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Now I am seeing `pool-229-thread-25` ... hmm.. I could not remember I set that much pool... I will dig around..